# Asserting that method has been called in a promise with Mocha and Sinon

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, promise, mocha.js, sinon

I have the following simplified method and test, where I want to test that handleResponse() has been called.

The test fails with handleResponse() not beeing called at all. If I modify the code to run handleResponse outside the promise, the test completes successfully.

Is this because the promise is async, and the assertion is being run before the promise? If so, how can I wait for the promise to the completed before running the assertion?

Code:

```
export function fetchList(id) {
  // handleResponse(response); // Works here

  return (dispatch) => {
    service.getList(id).then((response) => {
      handleResponse(response); // Doesnt work here
    }, (error) => {
      addNotification(error);
    });
  };
}
```

Test:

```
describe('fetchList', () => {
  let getListStub;
  let handleResponseStub;

  beforeEach(() => {
    getListStub = sinon.stub(service, 'getList');
    handleResponseStub = sinon.stub(appActions, 'handleResponse');
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    getListStub.restore();
    handleResponseStub.restore();
  });

  it('should dispatch handleResponse on success', () => {
    const dispatchStub = sinon.stub();
    const id = 1;
    const returnValue = 'return value';
    getListStub.withArgs(id).resolves(returnValue);

    listActions.fetchList(id)(dispatchStub);

    sinon.assert.calledOnce(getListStub);
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(handleResponseStub); // Fails
  });
});
```

Comment: I don't think it's an issue with async, the stub won't be asynchronous. Did you check if maybe an error is thrown when you execute the test and addNotification is called rather than handleResponse?

Comment: Yes, no error is thrown. Both handleResponse and addNotification fails on assert.called().

Answer (score 0):

You forget add `async/await` to your unit test and change to `return service.getList(...)`. Otherwise, the assertion will execute before resolving the promise of `service.getList(...)`.

`listActions.ts`:

```js
import * as service from "./service";
import { handleResponse, addNotification } from "./appActions";

export function fetchList(id) {
  return dispatch => {
    return service.getList(id).then(
      response => {
        handleResponse(response);
      },
      error => {
        addNotification(error);
      }
    );
  };
}
```

`appActions.ts`:

```js
export function handleResponse(res) {
  console.log("handleResponse");
}

export function addNotification(error) {
  console.log("addNotification");
}
```

`service.ts`:

```js
export function getList(id) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve([]);
    }, 5000);
  });
}
```

`listActions.spec.ts`:

```js
import * as service from "./service";
import * as appActions from "./appActions";
import * as listActions from "./listActions";
import sinon from "sinon";

describe("fetchList", () => {
  let getListStub;
  let handleResponseStub;

  beforeEach(() => {
    getListStub = sinon.stub(service, "getList");
    handleResponseStub = sinon.stub(appActions, "handleResponse");
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    getListStub.restore();
    handleResponseStub.restore();
  });

  it("should dispatch handleResponse on success", async () => {
    const dispatchStub = sinon.stub();
    const id = 1;
    const returnValue = "return value";
    getListStub.withArgs(id).resolves(returnValue);

    await listActions.fetchList(id)(dispatchStub);

    sinon.assert.calledOnce(getListStub);
    sinon.assert.notCalled(dispatchStub);
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(handleResponseStub); // Fails
  });
});
```

Unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
  fetchList
    ✓ should dispatch handleResponse on success


  1 passing (95ms)

---------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File                 |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
---------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files            |    83.33 |      100 |    53.85 |    82.86 |                   |
 appActions.ts       |       50 |      100 |        0 |       50 |               2,6 |
 listActions.spec.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 listActions.ts      |    85.71 |      100 |       75 |    85.71 |                11 |
 service.ts          |       25 |      100 |        0 |       25 |             2,3,4 |
---------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/43186634